# The union of an arbitrary number of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I get the union of an arbitrary number of lists in Haskell. For example, I would like a function that behaves like the one below:

```
example1 = union' [1,2,3] [1,4]
example2 = union' [1,2,3] [1,4] [2,6]
example1
[1,2,3,4]
example2
[1,2,3,4,6]
```

Comment: Variadic functions in Haskell can't be implemented without jumping through a lot of hoops. Instead, you should define `union' :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]`, and pass a single list of lists as the argument.

Comment: Consider what the type of `union' [1,2,3] [1,4]` would be: is it a list, or is it a function that you can apply to `[2,6]`?

Comment: I would think that `union'` would be a list, but I'm a complete noob at coding in Haskell so don't take my word for it. I need to get the union of an arbitrary number of lists of numbers and then add together all numbers in the list. Do you have any tips on how to go about creating the `union'` function, cause I am quite lost?

Comment: [`unions` function from `Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:unions) module simplifies the job. `toList . unions $ Data.List.map fromList [[1,2,3,3,4],[2,2,3,4,4,5,6],[4,5,5,6,6,7]]` would return `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Comment: @K.Claesson That's the problem. If it's a list, you can't call it on further values. If it's a function, you can't treat it as a list. The "solutions" all involve typeclasses implemented by types that are neither lists *nor* functions, which is why you should do the idiomatic thing in Haskell and only worry about a function that takes a list of lists, rather than an arbitrary number of lists. (Strictly speaking, *every* function in Haskell takes a single argument; a function like `unionOfTwo :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` takes one argument, and returns a function that takes one argument.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function in Haskell only takes *one* argument. A "two"-argument function is really a function that returns another function that returns the ultimate return value. As such, there is no way for a function to take a variable number of arguments, because the return type of such a function wouldn't be well defined.

If you want to take the union of an arbitrary number of lists, your function should take a *list* of lists, since a list can contain an arbitrary number of elements.

```
union' :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
union' = foldr unionOfTwo []
  where unionOfTwo :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
        unionOfTwo xs ys = ...  -- left as an exercise
```

where `unionOfTwo` knows how to compute the union of *exactly* two lists. Effectively, `union'` sets aside the first list in the input, recursively computes the union of the remaining inputs, then computes the union of that result and the original first list. Put another way,

```
union' []  = []
union' (xs:xss) = unionOfTwo xs (union' xss)
```

Answer (score 2):

First a working code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}
module Main where
import Data.List (union)

class Unionable a t where
  union' :: [a] -> t

instance  Unionable a [a] where
  union' = id

instance  (Eq a, Unionable a t) => Unionable a ([a] -> t) where
  union' xs ys = union' (union xs ys)

main = do
  print $ (union' [1::Integer,2,3] [1::Integer,5,6] [1::Integer,7,3] :: [Integer])
```

mimiced from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.17/docs/src/Development.Shake.Command.html#cmd).

You probably want to use such a function with literals and sadly, as you can see here, it will not be convienent to use it with polymorphic literals, as you will need to specify the type of every argument.

In other contexts, the types of the arguments have to be clear and the expected type of the result must be clear too, otherwise, you will need to add such type annotations.

For normal code it probably isn't worth the effort.

Let's explain what happens here, the compiler sees:

```
(union' [1::Integer,2,3] [1::Integer,5,6] [1::Integer,7,3] :: [Integer])
```

and it thinks, we need

```
union' :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

do we have such a `union'`? A candidate for that would be provided by the second instance declaration

```
a ~ Integer
t ~ [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

but for that instance to be applicable, we need an instance of `(Unionable a t)` with those assignments. Do we have such an instance? Again the second instance declaration is a candidate, this time with

```
a ~ Integer
t ~ [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

but for that instance to be applicable, we need an instance of `(Unionable a t)` with those assignments. Do we have such an instance? Again the second instance declaration is a candidate, this time with

```
a ~ Integer
t ~ [Integer]
```

This time, we get such an instance from the first instance declaration with 
no additional constraints needed.

This means (ommitting the type annotations for clarity)

```
union' [1,2,3] [1,5,6] [1,7,3]
= unions' (union [1,2,3] [1,5,6]) [1,7,3]
= unions' (union (union [1,2,3] [1,5,6]) [1,7,3])
= id (union (union [1,2,3] [1,5,6]) [1,7,3])
= (union (union [1,2,3] [1,5,6]) [1,7,3])
= [1,2,3,5,6,7]
```